# Create Multiple Random Instances Of The Same Div On Click w/jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a scenario where something on the page is clicked, then a h1 will appear in a random place. However, I would then like that first h1 to stay in place and another appear in another random place and so on after each click. If the button was clicked continuously then the page will fill up with the same h1 tag. Almost like when Windows has a melt and loads of the same pop ups "pop up" and you have to click to get rid of them. I've tried doing this myself from searching other questions, but the code gets quite complicated when trying to adapt it from other users questions and answers.

So far I have managed to get the h1 tag to move randomly around the page. I've also managed to get it to clone the h1. However at the moment it all stays in one long list (apart from the original instance), instead of stopping in place with each instance as I'd like.

I've seen many different versions of creating the random part, so I'm entirely open to any ideas or completely new code to get this working.

```js
{
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn").click(function () {
    var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    var bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    var randPosX = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyWidth);
    var randPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyHeight);
 $(".words").clone().appendTo("body");
    $(".words").css("left", randPosX);
    $(".words").css("top", randPosY);
  });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.words {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1 class="words">
  Hello!
  </h1>
  <button class="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ynaj45m6/33/#&togetherjs=F9Vjsf1Uij

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two issues in your code. Firstly, `$('.words')` selects all the `h1` elements, so when you update their `css()` you're moving every single one of them. Instead, keep a reference to the cloned element and move that one only.

Similarly, if you only want to clone a single instance per click you need to select one `.words` element only, not all of them, and `:first` can be used for that. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    let bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    let bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    let randPosX = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyWidth);
    let randPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyHeight);

    let $clone = $(".words:first").clone().appendTo("body");
    $clone.css({
      left: randPosX,
      top: randPosY
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.words {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="words">
  Hello!
</h1>
<button class="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but do you know if there is a way to trigger this more than once with a single click? So click once and the h1's keep coming one after the other? Perhaps with a for loop or something, so the amount of instances can be defined? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, you could use an [`interval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to call a function at a given delay which adds a new `h1` to the page

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. There are 2 mistakes in your code. The first one is that the position should be absolute instead of relative. The second one is that you move *all* h1 to the new position. You only need to move the cloned one.

```
.words {
    position: absolute;
}

$(".cheeky").clone().appendTo(".wrapper").css("left", randPosX).css("top", randPosY);
```

Comment: Aha, I'm guessing I hadn't saved the fiddle properly, given the mixed up classes. I did simplify the whole thing to basics. Thank you for your answer!